# My N-400 denied, because I traveled outside USA more than six months (7 months),

Tags: usa, citizenship

My N-400, Application for US citizenship application, was denied because I traveled outside USA more than six months (7 months).

I have a green card since 2014 (5 years).

After I completed my interview without any problem, they asked me to provide evidence. After I submitted my documents, I received my application denied letter.

Please advise me what I need to do?

Comment: Get an immigration lawyer.

Comment: You might want to ask on [Expatriates.SE], where you also can't get legal advice but you might find some useful practical advice.  But if your actual travel history in fact disqualifies you from naturalization, then you have little choice other than to wait until you are qualified.  If USCIS made some mistake in evaluating your application or the evidence you submitted, then your next step will depend on exactly what that mistake was.

Answer (score 4):

According to [M-476](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/article/M-476.pdf), if you were out of the country for more than six months (but less than a year), you should provide documentation that you maintained ties to the US such as evidence of maintaining a domicile (home) like a rent or mortgage payment receipts and pay stubs, plus tax return transcripts. Here's the actual text:

> If you have taken any trip outside the United States that lasted six
> months or more since becoming a Lawful Permanent Resident, send
> evidence that you (and your family) continued to live, work and/or
> keep ties in the United States, such as:
>
> - An IRS tax return "transcript" or an IRS-certified tax return  listing tax information for the last 5 years (or for the last 3 years if you are applying on the basis of marriage to a U.S. citizen)
> - Rent or mortgage payments and pay stubs

If you did have that evidence but didn't send it with your application, I don't know whether or not you can appeal the decision with "new" information.